# ejabberd setup for multiple countries

Tags: ejabberd

I am new to ejabberd. I am working on an instant messaging that will run across the globe with different languages.
My question is,

1) do I need to setup different server for each of these countries in the word.

2) can I implement VOIP across ejabberd

3) can I authentic users using their phone numbers

Answer (score 2):

1) If you are worried about the 'language' option in ejabberd.yml, you can define a virtual host for each language, for example:

```
hosts:
  - "example.com"
  - "example.ru"
  - "example.pt"

host_config:
  "example.com":
    language: "en"
  "example.ru":
    language: "ru"
  "example.pt":
    language: "pt-br"
```

But notice that this 'language' option only is relevant when ejabberd is replying to a client that didn't specify its prefered language. Try yourself to set the option to a strange language, and then login to ejabberd with your prefered clients... ideally ejabberd should reply in your language, not in the server-configured one.

2) From what I know, that's a client topic, so the servers do not interfere.

3) Well, the account username can be a number, why not?

> 13:50:09.190 [info] (<0.544.0>) Accepted connection
>   ::ffff:127.0.0.1:43469 -> ::ffff:127.0.0.1:5222 13:50:14.311 [info]
>   (tcp|<0.544.0>) Accepted c2s SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication for
>   111222333@localhost by mnesia backend from ::ffff:127.0.0.1
>   13:50:14.390 [info] (tcp|<0.544.0>) Opened c2s session for
>   111222333@localhost/tka1